# Auto add data to postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys

I have a postgresql database with 3 Tables. One of these is to store the id from the other two tables as foreign keys. So i am using this table just to make a connection between the other two tables. The problem is that i don't know how to add id's data to this table from the other.

Comment: And when do you want to trigger this action I mean on what event you want to enter data in your table ?

Comment: In my app i'm using to INSERT to save data to the tables. So i want save the primary keys of the inserts as foreign key in the third table.

Comment: Hang on for the answer

Comment: please update op with insert example and tables structure

Comment: Did it solve your problem ?

Comment: I solved this. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

you can use postgresql triggers for automatic insertion of data here is a little example of how to do that

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_id() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $example_table$
   BEGIN
      INSERT INTO table_name(ID) VALUES (new.ID);
      RETURN NEW;
   END;
$example_table$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

now you can call the same procedure by using the triggers functionality in postgres

```
CREATE TRIGGER example_trigger AFTER INSERT ON table_name
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_id();
```